# Python dh key too small, which side is faulty?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

Using Python 3, I'm trying to connect using a SSL context to a remote SMTP host, but I get the following error:

> [SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1056)

Here's the code I use:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
import ssl, os, certifi

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH, cafile=certifi.where())
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

ssl_context.load_cert_chain(os.path.join(certsdir, 'certificate.pem'), os.path.join(certsdir, 'id_rsa'))
ssl_context.load_dh_params(os.path.join(certsdir, 'dhparams.pem'))

ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

smtp = SMTP(server_name)
smtp.connect((host, 25))
smtp.ehlo()
if smtp.has_extn('starttls'):
    smtp.starttls(None, None, ssl_context)
    smtp.ehlo()

smtp.mail(fromaddr)
smtp.rcpt(toaddr)
smtp.data(message)
smtp.quit()
```

Is the issue on my end, or on the destination's server end? Is there something I can do to avoid this issue?

I use `certifi` for the list of certificates, that is based on Mozilla recommendations and is up-to-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: Is the issue on my end, or on the destination's server end?

The server is offering a weak DH key, the client (your script) wants a stronger key. The problem should usually be fixed at the server side. And note that your call of `load_dh_params` makes no sense since setting the DH key is only relevant for the server side.

> Is there something I can do to avoid this issue?

Don't use DH ciphers in the first place. All modern clients support ECDHE ciphers which don't have this problem. DH is very slow anyway.
Usually the client would also choose a ECDHE cipher if offered and this error will not happen. While it might be that the TLS stack at the client is too old and prefers DH, such an old stack would usually not complain about a weak DH. It is thus more likely that the servers SSL stack is too old so that it does not offer the more modern ciphers the clients wants by default.

To make sure that no DH ciphers are offered by the client and thus ECDHE or RSA key exchange is used [set the ciphers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers) accordingly:

```
 ssl_context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT:!DH')
```

Note though that RSA key exchange is considered obsolete too since it does not provide any forward secrecy. You might therefore try if the server can do without DH and without kRSA by using a cipher string of `DEFAULT:!DH:!kRSA`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Just to clarify, when you say "the server is offering a weak DH key". is it me, or the server I'm connecting to? As for switching from DH ciphers to ECDHE, how can I do? (pointing to a link is perfect, you don't have to write an extensive explanation :) )

Comment: @CyrilN.: I was actually a bit confused about your setting of dhparam and though that you were implementing a server. But you are implementing a client and setting dhparam there makes no sense. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I would have a few other questions relative to SMTP, SSL, server/client. Can I reach out to you by email? (I have yours from your website, but I prefer to ask for permission first, as this would be out of context for here, but fully related to our domain of knowledge). Thank you in advance!

Comment: On this context: Do I need to load the dh params (`load_dh_params`) if they are not needed?

Comment: @CyrilN.: I rather prefer questions to be public and not by mail. This way everyone profits. And you don't need to load DH parameters if not needed. And these are definitely not needed in the client, no matter if DH key exchange is used or not.

Comment: Ok, too bad for me because I would really need some feedback on my implementations of SSL which have nothing to do here. That's why I was hoping for a discussion over email. Would it be good to drop DH and RSA as a server too? Also, is my current implementation - as a client - without DH and RSA, good, or am I missing some things?

Comment: @CyrilN.: In short: DH is not insecure but slow and is usually unneeded because modern clients support ECDHE. RSA key exchange should only be kept if old clients really need it too since there is no forward secrecy. The SSL context you create is wrong since you want the server to authenticate itself, i.e. SERVER_AUTH. I have no idea what this `SMTPBind` actually should do, do you mean `SMTP`? And disabling certificate validation is usually a big NO since this makes the code vulnerable to easy man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Is there really no way we could continue this discussion on a call or via email? We are just scratching the surface here :/

Comment: So I should use SERVER_AUTH instead of CLIENT_AUTH ?

Comment: Again, I'm not doing private support. The idea of SO is to have question and answers in the open so that all can profit from well formulated problem descriptions and useful answers. And that all can participate in this. As for SERVER_AUTH: yes and please have a look at [the documention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223095/discussion-between-cyril-n-and-steffen-ullrich).